# How to create a list of option tags from a JSON file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJS and I'm playing around with forms.
Specifically, I'm trying to build a list of `<option>` tags based on the entries in a (local) JSON file.

Stepping through the debugger, I can see that the values are read and parsed correctly. Yet, nothing appears in the rendered page and I'm not quite sure why.

Here's the component I wrote:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const countries = require('../Data/countries.json')

class Countries extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countries: countries,
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Countries">
        <select name={this.props.name}>
        {
          Object.entries(this.state.countries).forEach((entry, _) => {
            let key = entry[0]
            let value = entry[1]
            return <option value={key}>{value}</option>
          })
        }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Countries;
```

The JSON file comes from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umpirsky/country-list/master/data/en_GB/country.json.
So, entries are the likes of `"CC": "Country name"`.

In the main `App.js`, I instantiate `Countries` like this:

```
<Countries name="country" />
```

I can't see anything obvious that I am missing. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#forEach` has no return value and the `return` inside the callback does nothing

Use `Array#map()` instead

```
 <select name={this.props.name}>
    {
      Object.entries(this.state.countries).map((entry, _) => {
        let key = entry[0]
        let value = entry[1]
        return <option value={key}>{value}</option>
      })
    }
 </select>
```

Or using Object.keys()

```
 <select name={this.props.name}>
    {
      Object.keys(this.state.countries).map(key => {           
        return <option value={key}>{this.state.countries[key]}</option>
      })
    }
 </select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Googling a bit about the differences between `forEach` and `map` I've come across [these two statements](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f) which might be useful to whoever stumbles upon a similar problem: `forEach()` — executes a provided function once for each array element.
`map()` — creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: MDN Docs are good resource. Tell you what gets returned https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach